# How to derive Clopper-Pearson interval's F and beta approximation?

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data, binomial-distribution, references

It is well-known that there is an approximation of the Clopper-Pearson exact Confident Interval for binomial test.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)
it just simply claimed, without any reference that:

> Because of a relationship between the cumulative binomial distribution
>   and the beta distribution, the Clopper-Pearson interval is sometimes
>   presented in an alternate format that uses quantiles from the beta
>   distribution. $$B\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}; x, n - x + 1\right) < \theta
> < B\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}; x + 1, n - x\right) $$

And later I found in [C-P](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/4/404) that this canbe regarded as an interpolation of the binomial c.d.f. due to the CI-belt discrete arguement. But I still have no clue about how it is derived.

$$\left( 1 + \frac{n - x + 1}{x\,\,F\!\left[1 - \frac{1}{2}\alpha; 2x, 2(n - x + 1)\right]} \right)^{-1}< \theta < \left( 1 + \frac{n - x}{\left[x + 1\right]\,F\!\left[\frac{\alpha}{2}; 2(x + 1), 2(n - x)\right]} \right)^{-1} $$

And then Agresti also touched it in his *Categorical Data Analysis, 3ed* and leave it:

> ...from connections between binomial sums and the incomplete beta
>   function and related cdf's of beta and F distributions, the confidence
>   interval is...

Now I want to ask for a reference which gives full details about the proof of this approximation form to Clopper-Pearson CI since I have already spent quite a while on it.

FYI:[Agresti](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2685469?) and [C-P](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/4/404) did not solve the problem in their papers, I want a paper or a book which fully gives the arguement about the incomplete Beta function calculation since I myself is not familiar with this sort of manipulation.

Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428803/how-to-derive-clopper-pearson-intervals-f-and-beta-approximation math.se copy.

Comment: The [on topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help asks that we don't cross post; it requests that we choose one best location and post there. If you later decide a different site is better, you can flag to have it migrated.

Answer (score 1):

The using of beta distribution to construct the limits of the Biomial Proportions (Clopper-Pearson Formula) is ilustrated in the article "*Confidence Bounds & Intervals for Parameters Relating to the Binomial, Negative Binomial, Poisson and Hypergeometric Distributions*" by Fritz Scholz (2008). You can get it from:
http://www.stat.washington.edu/fritz/DATAFILES498B2008/ConfidenceBounds.pdf

Comment: While this link may theoretically answer the question, the help on [how to answer questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) under "Provide context for links" asks that we "*quote the most relevant part of an important link*"; as such [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.